# Sending Telemetry to HTML page using PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to make a simple webpage where I can upload the data from my sensors using GET requests. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="telemetry">
        <h1>Current Telemetry:</h1>
<?php
    $Temp=$_GET["temperature"];
    $Humidity=$_GET["humidity"];
    echo "Temperature = ".$Temp."Humidity = ".$Humidity;
?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So I want to make a continious GET requests like /iot.php?

`temperature=123&humidity=123` from my device, so it will refresh the page and show an actual data, but it doesn't show any updates, could you explain it please?

Comment: WIth ajax request via javascript?

Comment: You are mixing up two different functionalities: functionality 1) Parse values from IoT device to page with a GET and functionaility 2) refreshing the page and displaying the values. You can combine them on one page but you need to get rid of the meta tag and refresh the page from Javascript (so that only the browser will refresh) AND you need to store the values somewhere when you get parsed data, and fetch those values before displaying the page.